# US NOTAM Office disclaims foreign NOTAM accuracy or completeness?

Tags: airport, notam

> United States NOTAM Office disclaims foreign NOTAM accuracy or completeness. Aircrews are highly encouraged to check host nation sources for supplementary NOTAM information. [Source](https://www.notams.faa.gov/about.html)

What does mean exactly?

Answer (score 6):

What that means is that the US NOTAM office does not have any jurisdiction or control over foreign generated NOTAMS, therefore they cannot vouch for their accuracy.